# python how to remove $ sign and space

Tags: python

I have this function

```
def remove_dollar(s):
```

i want to remove space,$ sign from input value and convert into float.Input value may be like this

```
remove_dollar("12") == 12.0
remove_dollar("$123") == 123.0
remove_dollar("  $1234") == 1234.0
remove_dollar(" $42.3 ") == 42.3
```

Comment: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def remove_dollar(s):
    return float(s.replace('$','').replace(' ',''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.strip()` to remove the whitespaces around the string, and `str.replace()` to replace the `$` with a empty character.

```
def remove_dollar(s):
    return float(s.strip().replace('$',''))
```

The output will then be

```
print(remove_dollar("12"))
print(remove_dollar("$123"))
print(remove_dollar("  $1234"))
print(remove_dollar(" $42.3 "))
#12.0
#123.0
#1234.0
#42.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.strip()` method of strings:

```
" $42.3 ".strip(" $")
>>>> '42.3'
```

Its argument is a string containing characters you want to remove from beginning and end of your string.

Then you can convert the result to float using `float()`.

So your function should be:

```
def remove_dollar(s):
    return float(s.strip(" $"))
```